# nvd3 контроль в две строки

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть стандартны пример nvd3 [stacked bar](https://jsfiddle.net/aufpmb8o/1/)  с добавление контролей

`chart.showControls(true);`

При изменении размера экрана происходит пересечение контролей с легендой :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли расположить контроль в две строки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал играться с

`d3.select('.nv-controlsWrap').attr("transform","translate(...,...) rotate(...)");`

но они только двигают легенду в целом а не превращают в две строки.

## Update

Решение предложенное @Mark на [EN_SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796948/nvd3-controls-into-2-line) :

```
d3.select('.nv-controlsWrap .nv-series:nth-child(2)')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 25)');
```

новый [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aufpmb8o/2/)

Но при использовании легенды( нажатии на Stream0 например)
Происходит возврат к первоначальному положению.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли как то при использовании легенды сохранять положение контролей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ предложенный @Mark на [EN_SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796948/nvd3-controls-into-2-line)

Для того , что бы трансформация контролей происходила каждый раз после перестроения графика 
создаем функцию трансформации :

```
function stackControls(){
      d3.select('.nv-controlsWrap .nv-series:nth-child(2)').attr('transform', 'translate(0, 25)');
    }
```

И добавляем ее во все элементы:

```
nv.utils.windowResize(function(){
        chart.update();
        stackControls();
    });    
    d3.select('.nv-controlsWrap').on('click', stackControls);
    d3.select('.nv-legendWrap').on('click', stackControls);    
    stackControls();
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aufpmb8o/3/)